# How to append column values in Spark SQL?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, append

I have the below table:

```
+-------+---------+---------+
|movieId|movieName|    genre|
+-------+---------+---------+
|      1| example1|   action|
|      1| example1| thriller|
|      1| example1|  romance|
|      2| example2|fantastic|
|      2| example2|   action|
+-------+---------+---------+
```

What I am trying to achieve is to append the genre values together where the id and name are the same. Like this:

```
+-------+---------+---------------------------+
|movieId|movieName|    genre                  |
+-------+---------+---------------------------+
|      1| example1|   action|thriller|romance |
|      2| example2|   action|fantastic        |
+-------+---------+---------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupBy` and `collect_list` to get a list of all items with the same movie name. Then combine these to a string using `concat_ws` (if the order is important, first use `sort_array`). Small example with given sample dataframe:

```
val df2 = df.groupBy("movieId", "movieName")
  .agg(collect_list($"genre").as("genre"))
  .withColumn("genre", concat_ws("|", sort_array($"genre")))
```

Gives the result:

```
+-------+---------+-----------------------+
|movieId|movieName|genre                  |
+-------+---------+-----------------------+
|1      |example1 |action|thriller|romance|
|2      |example2 |action|fantastic       |
+-------+---------+-----------------------+
```